# Multiple shiny apps used for shiny dashboard inputs and deployment on different droplets

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

So i have a dashboard but i wish to break this dashboard into smaller apps. The smaller apps will provide inputs into the dashboard.

I have set up a droplet/shiny server. How would i go about doing this?
The dashboard and apps would need to be on the server so i can embed them on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, the question is too broad as it is right now. Here are a few pointers to get you going:
Since each shiny app "lives" on its own, they can't communicate directly with one another.

What you can do is to have a service which all the apps can talk to, i.e., some kind of data base. Once an app changes a status/field/table in the data base, the other apps see that and react accordingly.

I'm pretty sure you can accomplish this with a remote storage, not sure about local storage though.

RStudio has a good tutorial about persistent data storage in shiny apps, so I would start there: [Persistent data storage in Shiny apps](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html)

Comment: What happens if there are multiple users using the app?

Comment: @user9121879 The shiny server makes sure that each user has its own instance so they are completely separate. You have to make sure that when the shiny apps writes into the data base you use, they don't run into one another or try to write to the same place at the same time.
I'm not a DB expert, but sounds to me like a standard thing to do when using databases.

Comment: How can i write the shiny input slider data to the database? [code] dbWriteTable(con, "tbl_forecast", slidervalues(), append = TRUE) [code] as i'm getting an error

Comment: Usually you would use input$slider_name (replace slider_name with whatever the name you are using in the ui.R file/function). Note that this comment is outside the scope of your original question. 
This comment deals with Shinyapps help. If you found the answer (to the original question) satisfactory, please accept it as the answer.